# Why are QGIS's QuickMapServices on Mac (Apple) not showing up like on Windows?

Tags: qgis-plugins, windows, apple, quickmapservices

Is [QuickMapServices on Mac (Apple)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah8wL.jpg) limited for some known reason?

In [Windows QuickMapSerivces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdV33.png) there are many other WMS.

Need the Google Satellite WMS to be available on Mac (Apple).

---

The answer provided by gene solved the issue, forgot to do 
Web  >  QuickMapServices  >  Settings  >  More services  >  Get contributed pack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a Mac OS X or a Windows problem, simply add the contributed services

[image]

Then

[image]